# How to show only our NSLog() messages in Xcode's console?

Tags: xcode

I'm sure all Xcode 9 users need to explanation of the barrage of useless drivel that Apple is logging in everyone's processes these days. Is there a way to stop messages such as:

- "TIC read status..."
- "[MC] Reading from public effective user settings."
- "[WC] WCSession counterpart app not installed", etc, etc...

I keep seeing people mention the environment variable `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` to solve the problem, but setting this to `false` removes all my log statements too.

How do we get back to the simpler times when Xcode's console only shows messages from us?

Comment: I've been digging and digging and cannot find an answer to your very good question.  Maybe offer a bounty (you've got plenty of points) and it'll attract an answer.